# Can System have Same Pid and Port?

Tags: port

When I use `netstat -ano` appear like this:

```
Proto  LocalAddress RemoteAddress  State        PID

TCP    0.0.0.0:80       0.0.0.0:0              Listening 736

TCP    0.0.0.0:80       0.0.0.0:0              Listening 736
```

Does it work normally when I approach port 80?

Comment: Relevant: [`SO_REUSEADDR`/`SO_REUSEPORT`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14388706/35070) and [`Socket.ExclusiveAdressUse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.exclusiveaddressuse(v=vs.110).aspx). Alternatively, this may also be a strange behavior in the OS or netstat, maybe the socket is shown for each thread. Since you don't tell us what operating system you are using, I can only speculate though.